# How to read barcode which is stored in passbook in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, barcode-scanner

I have gone through many tutorials on how to read barcode using iPhone/iPad Camera. However, I would want to know how would I read a barcode which is already present in the passbook ?

**Scenario**

*Suppose I receive a barcode via email.

The barcode is now saved in passbook.

I would want to use my application to read this barcode.*

I would also want to understand how would I be able to read the barcode without the use of camera? Are there any custom libraries which can parse the barcode image or something on that lines?

I am targeting iOS 8.0+.

Comment: I am +1 this question because it could be helpful to others in future. Please post relevant links in your questions so that people answering must know what have you tried already.